# jquery scrollTop delay, postion fixed after scroll

Tags: jquery, settimeout, scrolltop

I'm wondering if anybody can point me in a direction to achieve the same effect as they have used on this website, [www.zakgroup.co.uk](http://zakgroup.co.uk/), im referring to the newsbar in the top of the page which scroll down to the top of the logo after a while and change the position for the logo to fixed;.

I have tried to pick the code from the site but havn't succeeded in that. I'm new in Jquery.

I have managed to get the scroll effect but how do I add delay and change the position to fixed..

My website is currently local unfortunately but here is the code anyway.

```
$(function(){     
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#logo').offset().top}, 1000 );
    });
```

I should somehow make if statements that set the property for the logo to fixed when it scrolls a certain amount of pixel?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// grab the The initial position
var mavTop = $('#my-nav').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  docScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(docScrollTop > mavTop) {
    $('#my-nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: 0});
    if(docScrollTop > mavTop + 300) {
      $('#my-nav').css('background-color', '#00f');
    }
  } else if(docScrollTop < mavTop) {
    $('#my-nav').css({position: 'inherit', top: mavTop});
  }
});
```

**demo: http://jsbin.com/siqasojinahu/1/edit**

Comment: Thank you for you reply.. That helped me with how the syntax is working. how do I animate that and put a delay on so the scroll happens automatic.?